# Multiprocessing processes in uninterruptible sleep (D) state when run from iPython Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-multiprocessing

I am performing a large parallel mapping computation from within iPython notebook. I am mapping a dataframe by subject and condition to an machine learning prediction function, and I want each subject and condition to be spread among 20 cores.

```
def map_vars_to_functionPredict(subject,condition):
    ans = map(predictBasic, [subject],[df],[condition])
    return ans

def main_helperPredict(args):
    return map_vars_to_functionPredict(*args)

def parallel_predict(subjects, conditions):
    p = Pool(20) 
    # set each matching item into a tuple
    job_args = list(itertools.product(*[subjects,conditions]))

    print job_args
    # map to pool
    ans = p.map(main_helperPredict, job_args)

    p.close()
    p.join()

    return ans
```

When I run these functions from iPython Notebook after starting the notebook, they run quickly and as expected (in 'Running' state at ~100% cpu in 20 cores). However, sometimes if I re-run the `parallel_predict` function right after running it for the first time, all 20 processes are marked as in uninterruptible sleep (D) state for no reason. I am not writing anything to disk, just having the output as a variable in iPython notebook.

As a last ditch attempt, I have tried including `del p` after `p.join()` and this helped somewhat (the function runs normally more often), but I still occasionally have the issue of processes being D, especially if I have a lot of processes in the queue.

**Edit:**

In general, adding `del p` after `p.join()` kept the processes from entering (D) state, but I continued to have an issue where the function would finish all the processes (as far as I could tell from `top`), but it would not return results. When I stopped the iPython Notebook kernel, I got the error `ZMQError: Address already in use`.

How should I properly start or finish the multiprocessing Pool to keep this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed four things and now 1) the processes no longer go into (D) state and 2) I can run these functions back-to-back and they always return results and don't hang.

To `parallel_predict`, I added `freeze_support()` and replaced `p.close()` with `p.terminate()` (and added a `print` line, but I don't think that makes a difference, but I'm including that since all of this is superstition anyway). I also added `del p`.

```
def parallel_predict(subjects, conditions):
    freeze_support()
    p = Pool(20) 
    # set each matching item into a tuple
    job_args = list(itertools.product(*[subjects,conditions]))

    print job_args
    # map to pool
    ans = p.map(main_helperPredict, job_args)

    p.terminate()
    p.join()
    del p

    print "finished"
    return ans
```

Finally, I embedded the line where I call `parallel_predict` in `if __name__ == "__main__"` as such:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    all_results = parallel_predict(subjects,conditions)
```